# SQL get a list of only supervisors

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a list of employees who are supervisors.

Employee table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| emp_id | fname    | lname     | start_date | end_date | superior_emp_id | dept_id | title              | assigned_branch_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1 | Michael  | Smith     | 2005-06-22 | NULL     |            NULL |       3 | President          |                  1 |
|      2 | Susan    | Barker    | 2006-09-12 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Vice President     |                  1 |
|      3 | Robert   | Tyler     | 2005-02-09 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Treasurer          |                  1 |
|      4 | Susan    | Hawthorne | 2006-04-24 | NULL     |               3 |       1 | Operations Manager |                  1 |
|      5 | John     | Gooding   | 2007-11-14 | NULL     |               4 |       2 | Loan Manager       |                  1 |
|      6 | Helen    | Fleming   | 2008-03-17 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  1 |
|      7 | Chris    | Tucker    | 2008-09-15 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      8 | Sarah    | Parker    | 2006-12-02 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      9 | Jane     | Grossman  | 2006-05-03 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|     10 | Paula    | Roberts   | 2006-07-27 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  2 |
|     11 | Thomas   | Ziegler   | 2004-10-23 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     12 | Samantha | Jameson   | 2007-01-08 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     13 | John     | Blake     | 2004-05-11 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  3 |
|     14 | Cindy    | Mason     | 2006-08-09 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     15 | Frank    | Portman   | 2007-04-01 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     16 | Theresa  | Markham   | 2005-03-15 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  4 |
|     17 | Beth     | Fowler    | 2006-06-29 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
|     18 | Rick     | Tulman    | 2006-12-12 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I can verify who are supervisors with this query:
`SELECT DISTINCT superior_emp_id FROM employee`

I am trying to select a list of only supervisors with this:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, e.emp_id
FROM employee e
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e2
    ON e.superior_emp_id = e2.emp_id
ORDER BY e.fname
```

But am not getting what I want:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| fname    | lname     | emp_id |
+----------+-----------+--------+
| Beth     | Fowler    |     17 |
| Chris    | Tucker    |      7 |
| Cindy    | Mason     |     14 |
| Frank    | Portman   |     15 |
| Helen    | Fleming   |      6 |
| Jane     | Grossman  |      9 |
| John     | Gooding   |      5 |
| John     | Blake     |     13 |
| Michael  | Smith     |      1 |
| Paula    | Roberts   |     10 |
| Rick     | Tulman    |     18 |
| Robert   | Tyler     |      3 |
| Samantha | Jameson   |     12 |
| Sarah    | Parker    |      8 |
| Susan    | Hawthorne |      4 |
| Susan    | Barker    |      2 |
| Theresa  | Markham   |     16 |
| Thomas   | Ziegler   |     11 |
+----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you please add a snippet of the other table you are trying to join.

Comment: @Hydrogirl it's a self join so the table is joined onto itself. Notice `employee e LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e_mgr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so an employee is defined as a supervisor if their id appears in the column `Employee.superior_emp_id`. We can reword this definition slightly and say an employee is a supervisor if there is at least one row in `Employee` with their id in column `superior_emp_id`. This can be accomplished with a `EXISTS` query and translates to the following SQL:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, e.emp_id
FROM Employee AS e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Employee e2
    WHERE e2.superior_emp_id = e.emp_id
)
```

---

Side note: you can actually write a query using the first statement. However, some optimizers have a very hard time with the `IN` keyword - or worse if NULL is involved - and as a rule I avoid this keyword wherever possible. For completeness though the first statement would translate to:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, e.emp_id
FROM Employee AS e
WHERE e.emp_id IN (SELECT superior_emp_id FROM employee)
```

---

Also: [the self join suggested by @YogeshSharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49103453/44853) will also work, provided you select the columns for the superior (`e1`) as opposed to the employee in `e`. This will however produce multiple rows for each person, one for each of their subordinates to be exact. This could be mitigated with the `DISTINCT` keyword, or by using the query above.

Comment: interesting. Never thought I could do this with a correlated subquery. I will admit I hate subqueries.

Comment: I know what you mean about using `IN` when there are NULL values in the list. I had some problems a couple a weeks ago. Do you think there might be a way to accomplish this with a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of a subquery, though?

Comment: Yes, @YogeshSharma's answer would work with the change I suggested. It would be an inner join, not a left join, and you need to select from the superior's row.

Comment: Just tried it. I worked except that it returned a lot of duplicates.

Comment: @RobertRocha Yes, I mentioned about this in my "Also" comment at the bottom of my answer, because the join is essentially returning one row for each person's superior.

Comment: Right. I solved the duplicate issue using a `GOUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Select first_name, superior_emp_id, last_name from table where id= superior_emp_id
```

Replace the column name it will help you to get the expected data